Why do $n^4+4$ and $(n+2)^4+4$ have a largish common prime factor?
It seems that $n^4+4$ and $(n+2)^4+4$ always have a prime factor other than $2$ or $5$. For example: $94^4+4$ and $96^4+4$ are both divisible by $4513$; $15^4+4$ and $17^4+4$ are both divisible by 257. I'm sure the reason is obvious, but I don't see it.

In fact both expressions have $n^2+2n+2$ as a nontrivial factor.

@Peter Oh. Duh.

$n^4+4 = (n^2+2n+2)(n^2-2n+2)$ and $(n+2)^4+4 =(n^2+2n+2)(n^2+6n+10)$ so they share a non trivial common factor.

Cf. Sophie Germain’s identity

Simpler: shift $,n\to n!-!1,$ then it's  $\ n^2!+!1\mid (n \pm 1)^4!+4,$ by $,(i\pm!1)^4 = (\pm2 i)^2=-4\ \ $

Or you could have brute-force computed their gcd by the Euclidean algoirthm $\ \ $
